# How can I get notification of answers or comments to my questions at my work e-mail address?

Tags: support, notifications, email

I am signed up on Stack Overflow using my own personal e-mail address, as I did not want to lose reputation and badges when moving from one job to the next.  At my current job, it is strictly verboten to use web mail clients or access personal e-mail accounts, so I would like to add a second (work) e-mail address at which I can be notified when someone answers or comments on one of my questions, but I cannot find any way to do that.

If anyone can point me in the right direction or tell me if this is possible, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The email address you use for notifications does not need to match the email address you use for logging in.

As long as you're just looking to change where your notifications go, rather than having them go to *two* addresses, just change the "Notification email" in your preferences. (Click your icon in the top menu bar to get to your profile, then go to the "preferences" tab.)

Answer (score 1):

You could also setup email forwarding from personal to your working email.